# Using for loops on command line - variable not working?

Tags: command-line, bash

Simple for loop on the command line:

```
cobrakai$for((i=1;i<=10;i+=1)); do echo "Welcome $i times"; doneWelcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 5 times
Welcome 6 times
Welcome 7 times
Welcome 8 times
Welcome 9 times
Welcome 10 times
```

...and if I want to put a date command in I can do this:

```
cobrakai$for((i=1;i<=10;i+=1)); do  echo $(date -v -1d "+%Y-%m-%d"); done
2013-08-04
2013-08-04
2013-08-04
2013-08-04
2013-08-04
2013-08-04
2013-08-04
2013-08-04
2013-08-04
2013-08-04
```

But, of course, I actually want the dates to count down, so I subsitute in the $i for the 1 but find I get...

```
for((i=1;i<=10;i+=1)); do  echo $(date -v -$id "+%Y-%m-%d"); done
-: Cannot apply date adjustment
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

I presume that's because $id is recognised as $(id) not ($i)d, so I try,

```
cobrakai$for((i=1;i<=10;i+=1)); do  echo $(date -v -($i)d "+%Y-%m-%d"); done
-bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: command substitution: line 1: `date -v -($i)d "+%Y-%m-%d"'
```

and

```
for((i=1;i<=10;i+=1)); do  echo $(date -v -$i d "+%Y-%m-%d"); done
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

but I'm getting nowhere - what's the key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
-"$i"d
```

or

```
-${i}d
```

I am not able to test the solution, though, as my `date` command does not recognize the `-v -1d` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newer bash/gnu utility set:

$ for((i=1;i<10;i+=1)) do date   "+%Y-%m-%d" --date="${i} day"; done

[image]